# Syncing exchange server with Google calendar for blackberry use

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, google-calendar, blackberry

My girlfriend's company won't allow her enterprise access to her exchange server on her blackberry, so I'm trying to figure out a way to sync her exchange calendar with her Google account so she can sync it with her blackberry.

I can't use Google sync to do this because she accesses her outlook on a remote machine (she works offsite), and I can't seem to get davmail to work either.

Perhaps there's a way I can configure her work outlook to export calendar events to another account she can use to sync to her blackberry - a non-work account?

She was able to sync her work email with her blackberry, but the calendar is presenting problems...

Answer (score 1):

I use [SyncMyCal](http://www.syncmycal.com/). It it not free, but just works. I have been using it for years.

Comment: This syncs with Outlook, not with Exchange Server...

Comment: BTW, for syncing with outlook there is a free program available as well: http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955